# Cauchy sequences according to Cauchy...

Tags: real-analysis, math-history, cauchy-sequences

(It may be that this question "does not show research effort". Sorry --  it's not a question with mathematical content, so it's impossible to figure out the answer; it's a question about who said what when, and I have no idea where to look for the answer...)

Recent comments about one of our regulars being a better mathematician than Cauchy reminded me::

I gather that Cauchy never referred to "cauchy sequences"; rather his definition of "convergent sequence of reals" was the same as our definition of "cauchy sequence of reals".

**Q1:** Is that more or less correct?

If yes: Presumably he used the fact which is expressed in  modern terminology by saying that every cauchy sequence of reals is convergent.

**Q2:** Was he aware that this fact amounts to a significant *assumption* about $\Bbb R$,  or did he regard the fact as a self-evident *truth*? (Come to think of it there's a third possibility; that he proved (or "proved") the fact. This seems unlikely, but if so he proved it from what assumptions?)

Comment: Some older books used "fundamental sequence" where modern textbook writers use "Cauchy sequence".  This may still be the preferred terminology in some languages.  So the theorem of Cauchy would be: Every fundamental sequence (of real numbers) converges.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_sequence  But I await an answer here.

Comment: See Robert Bradley & CEdward Sandifer (editors), [Cauchy's Cours d’analyse : An Annotated Translation (Springer, 2009)](https://books.google.it/books?id=M0or-HGe7D0C&pg=PA85), page 85 : "We call a *series* an indefinite sequence of quantities, $u_0, u_1, u_2,\ldots$, which follow from one to another according to a determined law. These quantities themselves are the various terms of the series under consideration. Let $s_n = u_0+ \ldots + u_{n−1}$ be the sum of the first $n$ terms. ... 1/2

Comment: @GEdgar When you refer to that as his "theorem"  are you meaning to assert that he gave (something that he considered to be) a proof?

Comment: If, for ever increasing values of $n$, the sum sn indefinitely approaches a certain limit $s$, the series is said to be *convergent*, and the limit in question is called the *sum* of the series." 2/2

Comment: And see page 86-87 for Cauchy Convergence Criterion.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks. Google books, lemme make a note of that. Looking at those two pages it seems that the answer to Q1 is "not really", while in fact he stated the Fact without proof.

Comment: Yes; the "Conversly..." is stated but not proved.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA : Of course not, as he clearly knew that his name was written as "Cauchy".